# How to strip parameters from a variable in a makefile

Tags: gcc, makefile, gnu, gnu-make

Below is a variable I am using in a makefile.

```
copt = -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -g -c
```

I want to remove -mthumb and replace it with some other option.
Is there any way I can strip the option and add few other options.
I know how to add : Example - copt += -O3 but don't know how to remove the already existing options.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> `$(subst from,to,text)`
>
> Performs a textual replacement on the text text: each occurrence of from is replaced by to. The result is substituted for the function call.

In your case:

```
newopts = $(subst -mthumb, new_opt, $(copt))
```

Answer (score 1):

A tad safer than `$(subst...)` to to use something that operates on whole words:

```
newopts := $(filter-out -mthumb,${opts}) more opts
```

Answer (score -1):

`sed` works well:

```
sed -i 's/old_word/new_word/g' makefile
```

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: What happens when a user specifies `copt` on the command line?