# How to replace options in CFLAGS or CXXFLAGS

Tags: gnu-make

I'm trying to use GNU Make's [text substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html) to change an existing (and possibly missing) optimization level with `-O1`. Here's what I am using:

```
# Valgrind testing. Issue 'make valgrind'.
ifneq ($(filter valgrind,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),)
$(info: Valgrind build)

CXXFLAGS := $(CXXFLAGS:-g?=-g3)
CXXFLAGS := $(CXXFLAGS:-O?=-O1)

ifeq ($(findstring -DVALGRIND_BUILD,$(CXXFLAGS)),)
$(info: adding -DVALGRIND_BUILD)
CXXFLAGS += -DVALGRIND_BUILD
endif # -DVALGRIND_BUILD

ifeq ($(findstring -O,$(CXXFLAGS)),)
$(info: adding -O1)
CXXFLAGS += -O1
endif # Optimizations

endif # Valgrind
```

I believe I am invoking this rule or function from the manual:

```
$(var:pattern=replacement)
```

Things are not working as expected. The define is added, but the substitution is not occurring:

```
$ CXXFLAGS="-DNDEBUG -g2 -O3" make valgrind
g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -DVALGRIND_BUILD -c cryptlib.cpp
g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -DVALGRIND_BUILD -c cpu.cpp
g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -DVALGRIND_BUILD -c integer.cpp
...
```

I also tried to `$(filter-out ...)` (thinking I could add the desired optimization afterwards), but that did not work either:

```
CXXFLAGS := $(filter-out -g?,$(CXXFLAGS))
CXXFLAGS := $(filter-out -O?,$(CXXFLAGS))
```

Here's a similar question with answers that suggest both `subst` and `filter-out`: [How to strip parameters from a variable in a makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14844955/608639). But I can't seem to get the methods to work as expected.

How do I perform the replacement?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use '%' instead of '?' like this?

```
CXXFLAGS := $(CXXFLAGS:-g%=-g3)
```

or

```
CXXFLAGS := $(patsubst -g%,-g3,$(CXXFLAGS))
```

I can't access any linux box right now.
So, I couldn't confirm this. :p

Comment: *"Why don't you use `%`"* - According the the manual, the `?` matches a single character in GNUmake. See [Wildcards](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rules.html#Rules) in the manual.

Comment: Patterns in GNU make don't use '?' as a wild character.

Comment: The wildcards section is _only_ relevant for filename matching; it explicitly says it's performed on targets and prerequisites: this is neither of those.  You should read the documentation describing substitution references (which is what this is); it says that the initial string must contain a single `%` character.